# Chrome background autoplay does not work properly

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the PHP script I use to add the player:

```
echo "<audio id='my_audio' src='img/default-sound.mp3'></audio>";
```

And to play it I use this script:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        if (document.getElementById("my_audio") == null) {
            alert("null");
        } else {
            alert("yay");
            document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
        }
    }
</script>
```

The alerts is just for testing purpose. The issue is: When opening my page in Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge, it all runs fine, the alert shows up, and the mp3 file is played once. But when opening with Google Chrome, only the alert shows up. Then, if I spam the page refresh button a few times, suddenly the sound plays. What might be causing this issue?

Comment: Why are you re-posting the question instead of editing the [old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63394979/autoplay-mp3-in-background)?

Comment: @AlonEitan I have been told earlier that if a post is over an hour old, don't edit, because then the comments/answers wont make sense. Is that not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

**Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:**

1. Muted autoplay is always allowed.
2. Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
   User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
   On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound.
3. The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on desktop.
4. Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

Answer (score 0):

enable/disable/set default auto-play settings (and many more)in :

> chrome://flags

But it just works on the computer you configured it.

Comment: There are no settings there for auto-play. Maybe because my computer is a part of an organization.